# Fuzzy search in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, fuzzywuzzy

I have a large csv file (>96 million rows) and seven columns. I want to do a fuzzy search on one of the columns and retrieve the records with the highest similarity to the input string.
The file is managed by spark and I load it via pyspark into some dataframe. Now I want to use something like fuzzywuzzy to extract the rows matching the best.

But the fuzzywuzzy function extract returns something that I cannot work with:

`process.extract("appel", df.select(df['lowercase']), limit=10)`

Result:
`[(Column<'lowercase'>, 44)]`

df is the pyspark dataframe (load using spark.read.csv), the column I want to search on is 'lowercase' and I want to retrieve all other columns for the respective rows plus the similarity score.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    
    
def match_string(s1, s2):
    val = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(s1, s2)
    return val
    
MatchUDF = udf(match_string, StringType())
    
scores_df = df.withColumn("similarity_score", MatchUDF(F.col("name_1"), F.col("name_2")))\
            .withColumn("run_date", F.current_date())
    
scores_df.show()
```

Comment: This answer is the correct parallel approach in PySpark, unlike tinman72's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using other python libraries like [Rapidfuzz](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/), which computes fuzzy string match taking an input string and list of strings, as input.
You can use choose your desired string match algorithm to compute appropriate matches.

The code would look something like this:

```
# pip install rapidfuzz
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process

input_string = 'appel'
query_list = df.lowercase.values

results = process.extract(input_string, query_list, scorer=fuzz.token_ratio, limit=1)

# output format = [('string1', confidence_score, index_in_list), ...]
```

Comment: That results in a TypeError:
```TypeError: object of type 'DataFrame' has no len()```

And also, I need the other columns for that entry. And not only the similar string.

Comment: I have edit my answer, hopefully that should resolve the error.

Comment: To create a new column for each entry you can store the values in a list and then use `df['new_column'] = new_list`.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'I want to retrieve all other columns for the respective rows' ?
Do you want to retrieve rows or columns?

P.s. - You can try loading the pyspark into a pandas dataframe and run the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

First create a list selecting only the lowercase column:

`lowerList = [str(row['lowercase']) for row in df.collect()]`

Then from here, you can extract the top 10:

```
top10 = process.extract("target phrase", lowerList, limit=10)
```

Then you can print

```
print(top10)
```